# UI automation cross-platform (Windows and Mac OS X) open source APIs/frameworks?

Tags: user-interface, frameworks, open-source, automation, cross-platform

Does anyone know of any UI automation cross-platform (Windows and Mac OS X) open source APIs/frameworks available for automating external GUI applications from inside a separate application programmatically?

Through searching, I've found a couple commercial cross-platform UI automation products, but obviously they wouldn't allow embedding in an open-source cross-platform application nor would they permit calling them from code (I would be calling it from Objective-C/Cocoa and/or .NET/Mono)...

I'm aware of (but haven't tried yet) the open source "white" project for .NET however that of course only works on Windows since it has a dependency on the Microsoft UI Automation framework.

Answer (score 4):

Image-driven UI automaion is the best solution so far.
Please have a look at sikuli.org.

Comment: Thanks!  Great find.  Looks very interesting and of course cross platform!  :)  The image driven is an approach I never heard of (most UI automation APIs focus on controls themselves (textboxes, labels, windows, dropdownlists, etc).  But this is interesting too.  I wonder what happens if the screen doesn't exactly match the picture?  I will dig deep into the documentation.  Really cool and highly promising!

Comment: Sikuli looks totally awesome. Very excited about using that.

Comment: Sikuli looks SIcK!!! ;-)

Comment: You will see that sikuli misses some parts in the picture especially when it comes to antializing. It is not the silver bullet but it is close.